# DIY Attic ladder or hire someone?

Tags: attic, diy-vs-pro, ladder, attic-door

This is what my attic access looks like. Is it feasible to install ladder access myself or should I hire someone?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a panel that you push up into the attic?

Comment: Who's to say what you can can't do except you. Here's a nice play-by-play https://www.thisoldhouse.com/attics/21016340/how-to-install-pull-down-attic-stairs

Comment: Something you’ll have to do is some shopping discovery to find out if the hole in your ceiling is compatible with existing ladder kits. From there, it’s either diy if you’re handy and have extra hands or hired out if you don’t feel like it.

Comment: An attic ladder often drops down in a direction parallel to the trusses or joists. Your photo shows the portable ladder standing perpendicular to the trusses; it appears to be in a closet. Is there a wall nearby preventing the ladder from running the other way? You might have to search for a compatible attic ladder (I don't know whether any exists).

Comment: @GregHill Is that a code thing or a general "good practice" thing?

Comment: @Nelson it's a physical space availability thing. Most (all?) pre-fab attic ladder assemblies have the ladder width the width between two ceiling joists, with the opening long enough (parallel with the joists) to store the ladder in as many folding/sliding sections as necessary/practical. It's also _very_ difficult to get a human body up a ladder then between joists if one goes up perpendicular to the joist direction, never mind doing so while carrying boxes to be stored in the attic.

Comment: @Nelson In a cursory search I noted several models from Louisville and Werner which fit a rough opening 54 inches long. That could only go in a direction parallel to the trusses/joists. They probably design their products this way so they're ergonomically similar to stairs for the reasons FreeMan described.